# How Do I Make A Play Again Button That Restarts My Pygame From The Beginning Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

so I am remaking flappy bird and I wondering how I could make a remake button that restarts my game all over again [video](https://gyazo.com/7d23848f8aa1266383472e44e54324b1) right now I have it as crashing the game when it collides with the pip

right now I have it has quiting my game when I collid with the pips

```
            # colisions between the up platforms
        for pip in pips:
            if bird1.rect.colliderect(pip.hitbox):
                print("collided")
                pygame.quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

heres my full code

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

#this is screem height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#know we put screem name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs Flappy Bird Game")
    #---------------------------------------------------

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))
        smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("Candarai.ttf",40)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        
    #------------------------------------------------------


def text_objects(text, font):
    black = (0,0,0)
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def game_intro():

    # this makes it             
    snow_list=[]
    no_of_circles=100;
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for i in range(no_of_circles):
        x = random.randrange(0, 600)
        y = random.randrange(0, 500)
        snow_list.append([x,y])


        
    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (255,250,250)
    bright_red = (255,250,0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    intro = True
    while intro:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()



        window.fill((0,0,0))




        for point in snow_list:
            point[1]+=1
            pygame.draw.circle(window, (255,255,255), point, 2)

            if(point[1] >= 600):
                point[0] = random.randrange(0, 600)
                point[1] = random.randrange(-10, -5)

        clock.tick(FPS)



        font = pygame.font.Font("Candarai.ttf", 50)
        loltext = font.render("Blaste OF Immunity", True,(255,255,255))
        lolrect = loltext.get_rect()
        lolrect.center = ((250,100))
        window.blit(loltext,lolrect)

        font = pygame.font.Font("Candarai.ttf", 50)
        loltext = font.render("Classic Flappy Bird Game", True,(255,255,255))
        lolrect = loltext.get_rect()
        lolrect.center = ((250,160))
        window.blit(loltext,lolrect)

        font = pygame.font.Font("Candarai.ttf", 50)
        loltext = font.render("By:Habib I.", True,(255,255,255))
        lolrect = loltext.get_rect()
        lolrect.center = ((280,460))
        window.blit(loltext,lolrect)

                    
        button("Click To Play!",180,250,190,40,green,bright_green,main_game)


    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------





      

        pygame.display.update()











def main_game():
    #player class
    class bird:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.bright = [
                pygame.image.load("killers50.png"),
                pygame.image.load("killers51.png"),
                pygame.image.load("killers52.png"),
                pygame.image.load("killers53.png"),
     
                               
                                  ]
            self.bleft = [
                pygame.image.load("ms1.png"),
                pygame.image.load("ms2.png"),
                pygame.image.load("ms3.png"),
                pygame.image.load("ms4.png"),
     





                              
                                  ]
            self.bright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//15,image.get_height()//15)) for image in self.bright]
            self.bleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//15,image.get_height()//15)) for image in self.bleft]
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.isJump = False
            self.JumpCount = 10
            self.fall = 0
            self.speed = 5
            self.Walking = 0
            self.vel = 5
            self.color  = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.direction = "down"
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
                    # this makes the enemy move right and left
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 22)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)
            if self.Walking + 1 >= 33:
                self.Walking = 0

            if self.vel > 0:        # left
                window.blit(self.bright[self.Walking % 3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking += 1
            else:                   # right
                window.blit(self.bleft[self.Walking % 3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking += 1

    class platform:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.pipis = pygame.image.load("pip.png")
            self.pipis = pygame.transform.scale(self.pipis,(self.pipis.get_width()//3,self.pipis.get_height()//3))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)

        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y )
            window.blit(self.pipis,self.rect)
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 5, self.y + 4, 79, 552)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    class pip:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.pipis = pygame.image.load("pipo.png")
            self.pipis = pygame.transform.scale(self.pipis,(self.pipis.get_width()//3,self.pipis.get_height()//3))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + -11, 29, 100)

        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
            window.blit(self.pipis,self.rect)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 5, self.y + -200, 79, 552)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    #player and enemy
    white = (255,255,255)
    bird1 = bird(0,400,40,20,white)

    red = (255,48,48)
    platform1 = platform(600,300,50,550,white)
    platform2 = platform(800,200,90,550,white)
    platform3 = platform(1100,300,90,550,white)
    platform4 = platform(1300,400,90,550,white)
    platform5 = platform(1500,300,90,550,white)
    platform6 = platform(1800,200,90,550,white)

    # ROUND 2
    platform7 = platform(2200,300,90,550,white)
    platform8 = platform(2400,200,90,550,white)
    platform9 = platform(2600,300,90,550,white)
    platform10 = platform(2700,400,90,550,white)
    platform11 = platform(2900,300,90,550,white)
    platform12 = platform(3200,200,90,550,white)

    # rOUND 3
    platform13 = platform(3400,300,90,550,white)
    platform14 = platform(3600,200,90,550,white)
    platform15 = platform(3800,300,90,550,white)
    platform16 = platform(4000,400,90,550,white)
    platform17 = platform(4200,300,90,550,white)
    platform18 = platform(4400,200,90,550,white)

    # ROUND 4
    platform19 = platform(600,300,90,550,white)
    platform20 = platform(800,200,90,550,white)
    platform21 = platform(1100,300,90,550,white)
    platform22 = platform(1300,400,90,550,white)
    platform23 = platform(1500,300,90,550,white)
    platform24 = platform(1800,200,90,550,white)

    platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3,platform4,platform5,platform6,platform7,platform8,platform9,platform10,platform11,platform12,platform13,platform14,platform15,platform16,platform17,platform18,platform19,platform20,platform21,platform22,platform23,platform24]

    # sceond pip

    pip1 = pip(600,-160,100,50,white)
    pip2 = pip(800,-270,150,50,white)
    pip3 = pip(1100,-170,150,50,white)
    pip4 = pip(1300,-170,150,50,white)
    pip5 = pip(1500,-170,150,50,white)
    pip6 = pip(1800,-270,150,50,white)

    # ROUND 2
    pip7 = pip(2200,-160,150,50,white)
    pip8 = pip(2400,-270,150,50,white)
    pip9 = pip(2600,-170,150,50,white)
    pip10 = pip(2700,-170,150,50,white)
    pip11 = pip(2900,-170,150,50,white)
    pip12 = pip(3200,-270,150,50,white)

    # ROUND 3

    # rOUND 3
    pip13 = pip(3400,-160,150,50,white)
    pip14 = pip(3600,-270,150,50,white)
    pip15 = pip(3800,-170,150,50,white)
    pip16 = pip(4000,-170,150,50,white)
    pip17 = pip(4200,-170,150,50,white)
    pip18 = pip(4400,-270,150,50,white)


    # ROUND 4

    pip19 = pip(600,-160,150,50,white)
    pip20 = pip(800,-270,150,50,white)
    pip21 = pip(1100,-170,150,50,white)
    pip22 = pip(1300,-170,150,50,white)
    pip23 = pip(1500,-170,150,50,white)
    pip24 = pip(1800,-270,150,50,white)

    pips = [pip1,pip2,pip3,pip4,pip5,pip6,pip7,pip8,pip9,pip10,pip11,pip12,pip13,pip14,pip15,pip16,pip17,pip18,pip19,pip20,pip21,pip22,pip23,pip24]#window




    class orb: 
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

            




    class particleAndPoint:  
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            
    particleAndPoints = []
    # this is the orbs
    orb1 = orb(1500,100,50,550,white)
    orb2 = orb(2600,100,50,550,white)

    orbes = [orb1,orb2]
    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    platformList = []
    level = [" ",
                 "                                       ",
                 "                                                      ",
                 "                                                                                                                     ",
                 "                                                                p                 p                              p                     p                p                               p                                      p                      p                  p         p                 p                            p                    p                   p                    p                 p                    p                    p",
                 "                                                                                                                                                             ",
                 "                                                                                                                                                            ",
                 "                                                                                                                                                    ",
                 "                                                                                                                                                               ",
                 "                                                                                                                                                                  ",
                 "                                                                                                  ",]
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "p":
                new_platforms = particleAndPoint(ix*10, iy*0, 10,1010,(255,255,255))
                particleAndPoints.append(new_platforms)





    # the score text
    font = pygame.font.Font('Candarai.ttf',60)
    score = 0
    loltext = font.render("" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
    lolrect = loltext.get_rect()
    lolrect.center = ((130,60))

    # wow sound anime
    wowsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("wows.wav")
    explodesound = pygame.mixer.Sound("partexplode.wav")

    class particle:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.x_vel = random.randrange(-10,13)*1
            self.y_vel = random.randrange(-10,-1)*1
            self.lifetime = 0
        def draw(self,window):
            self.lifetime += 1
            if self.lifetime <30:
                self.x -= self.x_vel
                self.y -= self.y_vel
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(232,255,24),(self.x,self.y, 16,16))
    # draw the screen things
    # scrolling screen
    bg_shift = 0
    
    def redrawwindow():
        bg = pygame.image.load("bgs.png")
        bg_width = bg.get_width()
        bg_offset = bg_shift % bg_width 
    
        window.blit(bg, (-bg_offset, 0)) 
        window.blit(bg, (bg_width - bg_offset, 0)) 
     
    #player draw
        bird1.draw()
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.draw()
        for pip in pips:
            pip.draw()
        for particleAndPoint in particleAndPoints:
            particleAndPoint.draw()
        window.blit(loltext,lolrect)
        for orb in orbes:
            orb.draw()
        for particle in particles:
            particle.draw(window)


    fps = (30)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    particles = []
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False



        # if player collides with the obsticles add 1 to the player and delete the obstacle
         
                    

        for one in range(len(particleAndPoints)-1,-1,-1):
            if bird1.rect.colliderect(particleAndPoints[one].rect):
                score += 1
                bird1.speed += 0.2
                del particleAndPoints[one]
                explodesound.play()
                loltext = font.render("" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                lolrect.center = ((130,60))
                for x in range(60):
                    x, y = bird1.rect.center
                    particles.append( particle( x, y ) )

     



            # if ball collides with player1 show the particles
            # if ball collides with player1 show the particles
        if bird1.rect.colliderect( orb1.rect ):
            for x in range(60):
                wowsound.play()
                explodesound.play()
                x, y = bird1.rect.center
                particles.append( particle( x, y ) )

            
        if bird1.rect.colliderect( orb2.rect ):
            for x in range(60):
                wowsound.play()
                explodesound.play()
                x, y = bird1.rect.center
                particles.append( particle( x, y ) )
          # collisions between the platforms      
        for platform in platforms:
            if bird1.rect.colliderect(platform.hitbox):
                print("collided")
                pygame.quit()

            # colisions between the up platforms
        for pip in pips:
            if bird1.rect.colliderect(pip.hitbox):
                print("collided")
                pygame.quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # bird moving
        bird1.x += bird1.speed
        if not bird1.isJump:
            bird1.y += bird1.speed
            bird1.isJump = False

            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                bird1.isJump = True


            
            # this part lets you jump on platform
            collide = False
            for platform in platforms:
                if bird1.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                    collide = False

                
                # this makes the player fall down up to 
                if bird1.rect.bottom >= 500:
                    collide = True
                    bird1.isJump = False
                    bird1.JumpCount = 10
                    bird1.y = 500 - bird1.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    bird1.isJump = True
                bird1.fall = 0


        else:
            if bird1.JumpCount > 0:
                bird1.y -= (bird1.JumpCount*abs(bird1.JumpCount)) * 0.2
                bird1.JumpCount -= 1
            else:
                bird1.JumpCount = 10
                bird1.isJump = False


        # this scrolls my screen right
        if bird1.x > 300:
            
            bird1.x -= bird1.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x -= bird1.speed
                
            for pip in pips:
                pip.x -=bird1.speed
            for particleAndPoint in particleAndPoints:
                particleAndPoint.x -= bird1.speed
            for orb in orbes:
                orb.x -= bird1.speed
            # scrolling window
            bg_shift += round(bird1.speed / 2)



                
        redrawwindow()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
game_intro()
main_game()
```

I just want a basic functional button  that allows my game to restart and works when my bird collides with the pips

Comment: A good place to start would be encapsulating your game logic into a class, so the active instance of that class can be replaced with a completely new copy. That'll also make automated testing a lot easier.

Comment: ...that said, this is a bit broader than we like for a question -- there are lots of different ways to accomplish the desired end, and the logic given isn't exactly a [mre] (note the "minimal" aspect; a good question has code cut down to the shortest possible thing that demonstrates the problem, and thereby also lets question themselves be terse and clear).

Answer (score 2):

```
black = (0,0,0)
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',25)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
    window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()
    main_game()
    time.sleep(2)


    
    

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')
```